# JS - изменение класса без потери стилей

Tags: javascript, html, style

Есть html страница со списком элементов, который объединяет общий className и, соответственно, привязанные к этому классу стили. Есть ли способ полностью изменить класс элементов, но не потерять привязанные к нему стили?

PS: я пробовал копировать стиль с другого такого же элемента, но получается каша, либо я такой тугой(.

PPS: если это поможет, я могу привести [пример страницы](https://vk.com/search?c%5Bper_page%5D=40&c%5Bq%5D=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81&c%5Bsection%5D=people), на которой я пытаюсь произвести замену. Я изменяю класс элементов с класснеймом "people_row search_row clear_fix".

Comment: А новый класс добавить не вариант?

Comment: @Snowy-Owl что вы имеете в виду? Добавить стили для измененного класса? Но как их получить?

Comment: @Stepan А зачем собственно вы хотите избавиться от имеющихся классов ?

Comment: XY problem - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: Полагаю под новым классом коментарий выше имел ввиду дополнительный к имеющемуся.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList